# Getting the first x item from a list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Primer for Python Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation)

I have a string and I'm splitting in a `;` character, I would like to associate this string with variables, but for me just the first x strings is useful, the other is redundant;

I wanted to use this code below, but if there is more than 4 coma than this raise an exception. Is there any simply way?

```
az1, el1, az2, el2, rfsspe = data_point.split(";")
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes! Use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/21475):

```
az1, el1, az2, el2, rfsspe = data_point.split(";")[:5]
```

That "slices" the list to get the first 5 elements only.

Answer (score 6):

The way, I do this is usually to add all the variables to a list(var_list) and then when I'm processsing the list I do something like

```
for x in var_list[:5]:
    print x #or do something
```